# YAML indentation and interpretation for a Prometheus Kubernetes example

Tags: yaml

Given this YAML file:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus/prometheus/main/documentation/examples/prometheus-kubernetes.yml

It starts with:

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: "kubernetes-apiservers"

    kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: endpoints

    # Default to scraping over https. If required, just disable this or change to
    # `http`.
    scheme: https

    # This TLS & authorization config is used to connect to the actual scrape
    # endpoints for cluster components. This is separate to discovery auth
    # configuration because discovery & scraping are two separate concerns in
    # Prometheus. The discovery auth config is automatic if Prometheus runs inside
    # the cluster. Otherwise, more config options have to be provided within the
    # <kubernetes_sd_config>.
    tls_config:
      ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
      # If your node certificates are self-signed or use a different CA to the
      # master CA, then disable certificate verification below. Note that
      # certificate verification is an integral part of a secure infrastructure
      # so this should only be disabled in a controlled environment. You can
      # disable certificate verification by uncommenting the line below.
      #
      # insecure_skip_verify: true
    authorization:
      credentials_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

    # Keep only the default/kubernetes service endpoints for the https port. This
    # will add targets for each API server which Kubernetes adds an endpoint to
    # the default/kubernetes service.
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels:
          [
            __meta_kubernetes_namespace,
            __meta_kubernetes_service_name,
            __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name,
          ]
        action: keep
        regex: default;kubernetes;https
```

1. is `scrape_configs` a dictionary key?
2. does it contain a list item called `job_name`?
3. does this list item `job_name` have a value `"kubernetes-apiservers"`
4. does it then have a dictionary key called `kubernetes_sd_configs`?
5. does `kubernetes_sd_configs` then contain a value which is a list item called `role` with value `endpoints`?
6. does it then have another dictionary key called `scheme` with value `https`?
7. does it then have another dictionary key called `tls_config` with a dictionary value that is a dictionary key called `ca_file` which has a dictionary value `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt`
8. and another dictionary key called `relabel_configs` which has a list that has, as its first item, a dictionary with key `source_labels`
9. what is the data structure for the `source_labels` value?
10. how does the `action` dictionary key connect to `relabel_configs` (or `source_labels` - it doesn't seem to be a list item?

==== UPDATE

So, if `kubernetes_sd_configs` is a sibling to `job_name` why does it not also start with a `-`. i.e.

```
- job_name: "kubernetes-apiservers"
- kubernetes_sd_configs:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is scrape_configs a dictionary key?

Technically it is a *mapping key*. YAML terminology does not use the word *dictionary* however a YAML mapping is typically loaded into a Python dictionary if loaded with PyYAML.

> does it contain a list item called job_name?

No. The mapping contains a single key-value pair, whose key is `scrape_configs` and whose value is a *sequence* (YAML terminology does not use the word *list*) that has no further name.

> does this list item job_name have a value "kubernetes-apiservers"

No. The first item in the sequence is a mapping that contains a key-value pair with `job_name` being the key and `"kubernetes-apiservers"` being the value. Further key-value pairs follow.

> does it then have a dictionary key called kubernetes_sd_configs?

`kubernetes_sd_configs` is a sibling key to `job_name` in the mapping that is the first sequence item.

> does kubernetes_sd_configs then contain a value which is a list item called role with value endpoints?

As before, the key `kubernetes_sd_configs` has a sequence as value. That sequence contains a mapping with a single key-value pair whose key is `role` and whose value is `endpoints`.

> does it then have another dictionary key called scheme with value https?

That is another sibling key-value pair.

> does it then have another dictionary key called tls_config with a dictionary value that is a dictionary key called ca_file which has a dictionary value /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt

A key-value pair follows with `tls_config` as key and a mapping as value, whose content is a single key-value pair with `ca_value` being the key. Nowhere is a mapping value a key.

> and another dictionary key called relabel_configs which has a list that has, as its first item, a dictionary with key source_labels
> what is the data structure for the source_labels value?

The key-value pair with key `relabel_configs` has as value a sequence with one item. That item is a mapping whose first key-value pair has the key `source_labels`. The value of `source_labels` is a sequence, written in flow notation (in contrast with the previously used block notation, which has `-` starting items). Flow notation encloses the list items with `[]` and separates them with commas. There is no semantic difference to block notation. There is no requirement to give these values in flow notation, in fact if they are written in separate lines, they could as well be given in block notation.

> how does the action dictionary key connect to relabel_configs (or source_labels - it doesn't seem to be a list item?

`action` is a sibling key to `source_labels` and is part of the same mapping, which is the first item in the sequence value of the key `relabel_configs`.

> So, if kubernetes_sd_configs is a sibling to job_name why does it not also start with a `-`

Because it wouldn't be a sibling then. In this example:

```yaml
- job_name: "kubernetes-apiservers"
- kubernetes_sd_configs:
```

We have a sequence with *two* items, indicated by the `-`. Each item is a mapping. The first mapping contains a key-value pair with `job_name` as key. The second mapping contains a key-value pair with `kubernetes_sd_configs` as key, value is not shown. Since the two keys are in different sequence items, they are part of different mappings and therefore not siblings to each other.

Only by not starting a new sequence item does `kubernetes_sd_configs` become a sibling of `job_name`:

```yaml
- job_name: "kubernetes-apiservers"
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
```

Comment: see UPDATE above.

Comment: @Snowcrash Updated answer but please mind that SO is not a discussion forum and you shouldn't amend a question after it is being answered.

Comment: Great answer. Btw, YAML terminology does not use the word list